# CHROME-EXTENSIONS: runtime.onActivated not working for newtab and extensions page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project which produces a Chrome extension. In a background page I have a function named checkingProcess. This function is executed when a new tab is opened or a tab is updated. (I tried to catch the change of URL here.)

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
  checkingProcess(activeInfo.tabId)
})

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  checkingProcess(tab.id)
})
```

However, in newtab and extensions tab onActivated API calls are not working. After that, if I refresh the page it works because of onUpdated API call. How can I fix that?